# Struts 2.0 page navigation

Tags: struts2

The situation is something like this. There are three pages page1,page2,page 3

**Situation**

Page1 >> takes to >> Page 2 >> takes to >> Page 3

Page 2 is an intermediate page, which has links and links contains the params required by the action to reach page3.

```
<a href="<s:url action="gotoPage3" includeParams="none">
    <s:param name="request.accountId"><s:property value="#parameters['accountFrom.accountId']"/></s:param>
    <s:param name="request.accountFromId"><s:property value="#parameters['accountFrom.accountId']"/></s:param>
</a>
```

**What i want now**

I want to get rid of page 2 so that

page1 >> takes to >> page 3

**What I did**

In the struts config, I gave the outcome of action associated page1 to chain it action associated with the page2 link.

```
<action name="processPage1AndGoToPage3" class="dominos" method="processPage1AndGoToPage3">
    <interceptor-ref name="out-of-office-interceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="remove-hibernate-filters-interceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="request-deleted-interceptor"/>
    <result name="success" type="chain">gotopage3</result>
</action>
```

**Problem**

Now how do i pass the params to the action associated with the page2 (which takes you to the page 3). (I was passing them through link before)

Any pointer will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<action name="processPage1AndGoToPage3" class="dominos" method="processPage1AndGoToPage3">
    <interceptor-ref name="out-of-office-interceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="remove-hibernate-filters-interceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="request-deleted-interceptor"/>
    <result name="success" type="chain">gotopage3</result>
    <s:param name="page2Param1" value="page2Value1"/>
    <s:param name="page2Param2" value="page2Value2"/>
</action>
```

Note that **page2Param1** and **page2Param2** will be passed to **processPage1AndGoToPage3** the same way as calling http://server/webapp/processPage1AndGoToPage3.action?page2Param1=page2Value1&page2Param2=page2Value2